# Supported solidity compiler by truffle

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereum-classic

Hello I'm working on ethereum project using truffle framework, I want to know what is the latest solidity compiler version supported by truffle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You may specify...
>
> - any solc-js version (using semver) listed at [solc-bin](https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/list.json). Specify the one you want and Truffle will get it for you.
> - "native" to use a natively compiled solc binary (you'll need to install this yourself, links to help below).
> - a dockerized solc tag from one of images published [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/ethereum/solc/tags/).
> - a path to a locally available solc
> - "pragma" to have Truffle autodetect solc versions from your source files. This can be used to compile using multiple versions of solc.
> - a solc-js parser for faster docker and native compilations

Source: https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#solc

Answer (score 1):

Any of them, but you need to change the config file for Truffle, Truffle-config.js. If you want to use 0.8.7, you must change (or add) the following

```
compilers: {
  solc: {
    version: "0.8.7"
  }
}
```

next time you compile the contract, you will see that Truffle will use this version to compile the code.